# View image in native imageViewer in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have retrieved the uri of the image
But when i use

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,mediaUri));

the image is viewed in image viewer but i can also see other gallery images.

How to avoid this.

I only want the single image to open in image viewer.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/path/to/myfile.png"),"image/png");
startActivity(i);
```